# VS Code Git extension pull from option

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

While using git inbuilt extension, we use `git pull from` option. It pulls the code from selected branch and automatically merges into the current checked out branch.

But from what I know by using git is that `git pull` command is used to bring the changes from remote into local repository.

[image]

My question is that how it is performing auto merge from remote branch to local and also is there a way to always ask for Merge commit message when we use `git pull from` option.

Comment: From the command line, you can run `git fetch` and a separate second command, or provide any of numerous options to `git pull`. Since your question is strictly about VSCode and its extensions, though, I'll snip the [tag:git] tag and that way you won't get command-line-Git answers, which won't be helpful. :-)

Comment: @torek Thanks. It makes sense to remove the git tag. Its very silly of extension to use _**pull from**_ option and then put a merge commit on top of the current checked out branch. It is causing lot of trouble in our pre-receive hooks as we require a certain text to be added to all the commit messages. I think I might have to raise this issue to VS code github.